# canny segmentation produce unlinked edges

Tags: image-segmentation

I am trying to obtain edges from image using canny detector on a 16 gray level image (see image[image: gray level image]).

Although I am getting the boundaries, some regions present their boundaries disconnected (see image). [image: unlinked edges]

Anyone knows how can get the complete boundaries?

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, the Canny edge detection algorithm commonly leaves these kinds of artifacts when it's used to process low-resolution images.  As odd as it sounds, you can often achieve much better results by simply increasing the size of the image (for example, using bilinear interpolation).  I'm not sure what tools you're using, but in OpenCV, this can be done using a simple [resize](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize) function.  By increasing the width and height by a factor of 4, I can get the following boundaries:

[image]

Of course, if you look closely, you'll still see a few small gaps.  One possible solution to address that it to use [morphological transformations](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/opening_closing_hats/opening_closing_hats.html).  For example, if I use a morphological close operation on the above image, this will help connect the gaps:

[image]

It's worth noting that since your edge image appears to be black edges on white background, you will probably need to use a morphological open operation instead.

Also, note that the low threshold of the Canny operation can also have some influence on addressing the kinds of gaps you're seeing under some circumstances.  Before trying more computationally expensive approaches, it's worth trying to lower the low threshold to see if you can pull in the missing edges.

Comment: Hi @Aenimated1 
Your approach works well. The steps I follow were these:                      

gray = cv2.imread('image.tif',0)
big = cv2.resize(gray, (4*gray.shape[0], 4*gray.shape[1])) 
edges = cv2.Canny(big,5,10)
w,h = edges.shape
r = 500.0 / h
dim = (500, int(w * r))
small = cv2.resize(edges, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
small = ~small
small[small<250] = 0
io.imsave('small2.tif',small)

Now, I got what I wanted, thanks, Jaime

Comment: Glad it worked out.  Given the nature of your input image, it may also be worth considering a simpler algorithm.  Basically, all you need is to draw an edge wherever the input image has neighboring pixels with a different value.  I'm not sure if any OpenCV function supports that, but it would be easy to write and would be orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: Hey @Aenimated1, I have not think that way, this new approach is very simple and fast. I will give it a try too. Your ideas will be always welcome. Thinking out the box, some people says.

Answer (score 0):

Try use a sharpen filter before the canny contour detector to accentuate the edges.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Hi @kalyf-abdalla, thanks for your suggestion, but I have to say that my image it is not a usual gray level image, I mean, it is an image where every region has a particular gray level (no variability inside), so I think to apply sharpening does not help in my case, because boundaries are very well defined. I hope you understand my point, thanks anyway, Jaime